# Spring-Hadoop use spring object from mapper class

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, mapreduce

I use spring-hadoop version 1.
I am trying to use a Spring initialized singleton from the mapper class.

The start of the class is listed below

```
public class Map extends
    Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 


@Autowired 
MyObject myObject;
```

The problem is that it is not initialized.
I checked also in the log of spring that the myObject bean is initialized but it is not autowired.

After searching the web i found the link

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128572-Using-spring-context-in-mapper-how-to-autowire

I did not understand what the solution was there.

Answer (score 0):

Whether MyObject is any kind of Service or just a plain java bean.